# Provide user interface to insert language hints

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor

I find myself visiting [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/188688) on a regular basis to figure out what languages Prettify supports and by what names it calls them. I guess many others don't bother, or don't even know that language hints exist, leading to sub-optimal syntax highlighting in posts.

It would be great if there were some user interface to choose highlighting. What I have in mind is a small button next to the `{}` code formatting button. It might for example show a crayon, unless you come up with a better suggestion. Clicking on that button would open a dialog in much the same way the “add link” button does. That dialog could show a dropdown list of supported languages, and three buttons, titled “set for next block”, “set for all blocks” and “cancel”. I guess the “set for all blocks” button should insert its comment at the head of the post, as that would minimize surprises and users can still move that line around if they want to. The dropdown list *might* sort languages inferred from the tags to the top of the list.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I see a relation, but no duplication. Both questions are asking for another button, but where I'm asking for a button to *manually* choose the language, that question asks for a button to *automatically* format (i.e. reindent, I believe) code based on the *automatically* inferred language.

Comment: Not really a duplicate imo, this is not about formatting the actual code block, but about easily inserting language hints. (+1 from me btw!)

Comment: The question is, is this used often enough to warrant added clutter to the user interface?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: I can only speak for myself, but I know that I use language hints more often by far than headings or horizontal lines. I guess someone could use a data dump to obtain objective figures, but those would only show how often language hints *are* used, not how often the *should be* used even though they were not due to lack of a user interface.

Comment: Maybe insert this inside the button **`[?]`**

Comment: Let's see if this sees any response from anyone *this* time around...